# Can't stop/restart AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Please help. I can restart the AsyncTask. App crashes every time, when second call to updatePoi().

Here is my code:

1. I'm checking status of task and set cancel(true).

   ```
   public void updatePoi() {
       //new RefreshMapTask().execute();
       if (refreshMapTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING || 
           refreshMapTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING) {
               refreshMapTask.cancel(true);
           }
           refreshMapTask.execute();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Here is my AsyncTask. in doInBackground I wrote a break.

   ```
   private class RefreshMapTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();
           getMapView().getOverlays().clear();
           myPoiOverlay.clear();
           exitOverlay.clear();
       }


       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
           Application app = (Application)getApplication();
           Log.d(TAG, "exits count = " + app.getExits().size());

           GeoPoint pointToNavigate = null;

           for (Exit exit : app.getExits()) {

               for (Poi poi : exit.getPoi()) {
                   if (isCancelled()){
                       break;
                   }
                   //some code here
               }
           }

           //small code here
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
           getMapView().invalidate();
       }
   }
   ```

EDIT: added solution from comments into the question

```
 public void updatePoi() { 
//new RefreshMapTask().execute(); 
if (refreshMapTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING || 
    refreshMapTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING){ 
    refreshMapTask.cancel(true);
    refreshMapTask = new RefreshMapTask();
} else { 
    refreshMapTask = new RefreshMapTask(); 
} 
refreshMapTask.execute(); 
}
```

Comment: why you put doinbaground as void and return as null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `AsyncTask` instance can only be called once. To make a second call, you need to create a new instance.

Comment: I know. That's why I'm trying to kill asynctask, before calling it again.

Comment: killing won't do anything, its still the same instance.

Comment: cancel it then make it null and if you have to restart it then again assign value and call again

Comment: basically the reference object can be the same but the instance should be `new`

Comment: Thanks. Your answers helped.
My solution is:
public void updatePoi() {
        //new RefreshMapTask().execute();
        if (refreshMapTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING || refreshMapTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING){
            refreshMapTask.cancel(true);
            refreshMapTask = new RefreshMapTask();
        } else {
            refreshMapTask = new RefreshMapTask();
        }
        refreshMapTask.execute();
    }

Answer (score 2):

You can't *restart* a task. Each task object may only be executed once:

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

So create a new object each time you execute it, don't use the same object.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return null;
```

final code

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    Application app = (Application)getApplication();
    Log.d(TAG, "exits count = " + app.getExits().size());

    GeoPoint pointToNavigate = null;

    for (Exit exit : app.getExits()) {

        for (Poi poi : exit.getPoi()) {
            if (isCancelled()){
                return null;
            }
            //some code here
        }
    }

    //small code here
    return null;
}
```