# How to restart AsyncTask when wifi change?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have AsyncTask class called selecting-devices in my android code and when main-activity start it will execute the class but I need to start and stop when the if user change the wifi connection of the phone.how can I do this?

```
final selectingDevices select=new selectingDevices();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          select.execute();

     }
  private class selectingDevices extends AsyncTask{

       @Override
       protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
          if (!isCancelled())
          {
              startBonjour();
          }

                 return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onCancelled(){}
   }
```

Comment: you can't restart AsyncTask, you can register a receiver to detect when WIFI state changed, and CONNECTED then you can start a new AsyncTask

Answer (score 2):

You can't restart a task.You have to create a new object if you want to call it again.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642602/cant-stop-restart-asynctask).

Comment: I tried but got a exception also. I need to do that when wifi on/off or if user change the network.

Comment: @user3480706 Well for that just refer to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/package-summary.html).